# How to get application object into fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am changing my android mobile app to support both tablets and mobile phone. For this I am changing my activity class into fragment. In my activity class I have an instance of my application class created as below:

```
appCtx = (UnityMobileApp) getApplication();
```

Where `UnityMobileApp` is my Application class.

Now I want to create the same instance in my fragment class. Can you guys please help me solve this?

Comment: You have to post a bit more code snippet .Thanks :)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use `appCtx = (UnityMobileApp) getActivity().getApplication();` in your fragment.

Comment: Please note that in some cases above code will throw NPE because it may get called in a situation where `getActivity()` will return null (e.g. in the middle of rotation for example)

Comment: Use it in:
 
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        app = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication());
    }

Answer (score 4):

The method `getActivity()` may have possibility to return null. This may crash your app.So it is safe to use that method inside the `onActivityCreated()`. Eg:

```
private UnityMobileApp appCtx;
.
.
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(...){
...
}

@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
     appCtx = ((UnityMobileApp) getActivity().getApplication()); 
} 
...
//access the application class methods using the object appCtx....
```

This answer is derived from  Dzianis Yafima's answer asked by Ognyan in comments. Thus the Credit goes to **Dzianis Yafima's** and  **Ognyan** in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is looking for a Kotlin version. This works for me:

```
(activity?.application as YourApplicationClass)
```

Answer (score 2):

A Newer way:

```
Application application = requireActivity().getApplication();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying yo use application context from fragment you can not use `getApplication()` because that isn't method of Fragment class
So you first have to use the `getActivity()` which will return a Fragment Activity to which the fragment is currently associated with.

to sumup in your code,

instead of `this.getApplication()` you have to use `getActivity.getApplication()`

know more about `getActivity()` from [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively using Kotlin

```
fun bar() {
   (activity?.application as UnityMobileApp).let {
      it.drink()
   } ?: run {
      Log.d("DEBUG", "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻")
   }
}
```